# get_object from S3 with full path

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I used to have environment variables `BUCKET_NAME` and `FILENAME`.

This is my current code to get the file:

```
obj = self.s3_client.get_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=filename)
```

(where `self.bucket_name` came from `BUCKET_NAME` and `filename` came from `FILENAME` environment variables)

Earlier today, the "higher powers" changed the environment, so now instead of the bucket name I get the `BUCKET_FILE`, with the value `s3://bucket_name/filename`

This breaks my code, and I need to fix it.

Can I somehow use this string to get to the object? Or do I have to parse the `bucket_name` and `filename` out of it and keep the above code?

I searched S3 website, but I can't find anything other than `get_object`, which has `Bucket` (string containing bucket name) as a required parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you need to parse this string and get the bucket name and the key. Here is the function that AWS CLI uses to achieve this:

```py
def find_bucket_key(s3_path):
    """
    This is a helper function that given an s3 path such that the path is of
    the form: bucket/key
    It will return the bucket and the key represented by the s3 path
    """
    block_unsupported_resources(s3_path)
    match = _S3_ACCESSPOINT_TO_BUCKET_KEY_REGEX.match(s3_path)
    if match:
        return match.group('bucket'), match.group('key')
    match = _S3_OUTPOST_TO_BUCKET_KEY_REGEX.match(s3_path)
    if match:
        return match.group('bucket'), match.group('key')
    s3_components = s3_path.split('/', 1)
    bucket = s3_components[0]
    s3_key = ''
    if len(s3_components) > 1:
        s3_key = s3_components[1]
    return bucket, s3_key
```

Reference: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/awscli/customizations/s3/utils.py#L217-L235

Comment: Thanks. It just seems silly that S3 Client doesn't provide that...